# Calling a function from a derived class (or an alternative design)

Tags: c#

I have a C# class that detects and handles certain event. I'd like to derive subclasses from this class that react to the event in different ways, like this:

```
public class Detector
{
     void EventXHasHappened()
     {
         React();
     }

     protected virtual void React()
     {
     }
}

public class Derived : Detector
{
   protected override void React()
   {
      // Never gets called
   }
}
```

If I have understood correctly, this does not work since it is not possible to call a function in the derived class from the base class. Is there a neat way of doing this or is the whole approach wrong? (What would be a good design then?)

Comment: If you want to call the derived class from the base class, you've probably got your design wrong. Maybe the [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is what you need.

Comment: i think you are needing `interface`

Comment: What makes you think what you've got there won't work?  Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't understand what isn't working.. `Detector d = new Derived(); d.EventXHasHappened();` calls `React` of derived

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rA2DuM => There must be something else going wrong if the Derived.React is never called.

Comment: "this does not work since it is not possible to call a function in the derived class from the base class". It should work. Check if `EventXHasHappened()`has been called.

Comment: I suspect we do not see the cause because the example snippet does not show all of the relevant code. Please try and provide a [mcve].

Comment: As far as I can see, the only thing missing here is that you should declare `React()` in the base class as `protected abstract void React();`, and declare the base class as `abstract`.

Comment: EventXHasHappened is a private method which means that you cannot call it from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above works and does call the override of the derived. However if there is no implementation for the `React` in the base, and maybe no logic in instantiating one of those then I'd go with having it an abstract class, and `React` as an abstract method:

```
public abstract class Detector
{
    public void EventXHasHappened()
    {
        React();
    }
    protected abstract void React();
}

public class Derived : Detector
{
    protected override void React()
    {
        //TODO - your code
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Detector d = new Derived();
d.EventXHasHappened();
```

Comment: _"Your code above works and does call the override of the derived."_ If `EventXHasHappened` is actually called, that is.

Comment: So it seems, thank you very much. I must have made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @RikuErkkilä - you are welcome. I do recommend you rethink and check if indeed an abstract class will fit better in the design

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call a method in a derived class from itself; you will inherit the method EventXHasHappened, and so, to all intents and purposes, your code will work.

```
var d = new Derived();
d.EventXHadHappened();  // This will call d.React();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var derived = new Derived();
derived.EventXHasHappened();
```

This is valid code. React() will be called and you can override React() in any derived class and change the behaviour.

As the 'React' is a protected method, it can be called by any subclass. Also, the virtual keyword means it is designed to be overridden and used in base classes!

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question properly, may be you are trying to implement polymorphic behavior with react method:if yes then please follow the article below:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3024718/application-development/how-to-implement-polymorphism-in-c.html